# Force in class const member of class to be evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, sfml, compile-time

I am creating a game of Snake using SFML, and I have a concrete class `SnakeGame` that holds all the data members of my class, such as window size, size of a game map, color of the snake, etc. Thus, my class's internal members look like this:

```
class SnakeGame
{
private:
    //....
    const sf::Vector2u windowSize{400, 336};
    const sf::Color snakeColor {0, 0, 0};
    //...etc...
public:
    SnakeGame() : 
        renderWindow {sf::VideoMode{windowSize.x, windowSize.y}, /*other arguments*/ },
        snake {snakeColor, /*other arguments*/} 
        /*etc*/ 
    {}
```

However, this does not work and I get a window that is invisible, leading me to believe the arguments are not constructed yet. After reading another SO post, I read that `const` members as a class's members are not evaluated at compile time, but at runtime when the class is instantiated, and they behave otherwise in exactly the same ways as `const` variables. Thus, the variables `windowSize` and `snakeColor` are evaluated when I instantiate `SnakeGame` in `main`, so I cannot use them in the initializer list of my class. To try and solve this predicament, I decided to switch to `static constexpr` variables, but unfortunately I realized that `sf::Vector<T>` does not have a `constexpr` constructor, and neither does `sf::Color`. Of course, I guess I could just switch to integral types, such as `static constexpr unsigned int` for the window size, but eventually this becomes repetitive, especially for colors. So I decided to take another route. What I did was create another file `GameData.hpp`, and do this in it:

```
namespace gd //For game data
{
    const sf::Vector2u windowSize{400, 336};
    const sf::Color snakeColor {0, 0, 0};
    //...etc...
}
```

However, I do not like this solution, since even if this data is now evaluated at compile time, it is also accessible to all my classes if they include the appropriate header file, not just to `SnakeGame`. In this way, I feel like the internal data structure of my class is being revealed. Which leads to my question, which is: *Is there a way to force `const` members of a class to be evaluated at compile time in a way such that these variables can be used in initializer lists with the guarantee that they will constructed?*

Comment: Why don't you simply use `static` members (non `constexpr`)?

Comment: Or reorder your members in correct order.

Comment: You can also move declarations of these fields above declarations of fields depending on them because class fields are constructed in the order you declare them.

Comment: @JérémiPanneton  I would have done that, but I want to initialize the members inside the class.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have done what you said, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options here, all of which have tradeoffs. I’ve ranked them in rough order of what I consider best to worst, but your tradeoffs may be different.

- Refactor your code so that color and window size aren’t global constants. As a player, I want a green snake, not a black one, and I want a board which is twice as big. This probably involves keeping them as member variables, but not constants this time, and maybe re-ordering them so you can use them in the initialization of other member variables.
- Set your compiler to C++17 mode, and make `snakeColor` an `inline static const` variable. This is the best option if you want a header-only library and can use C++17.
- Make it a `const static` data member, and add `const sf::Color SnakeGame::snakeColor {0, 0, 0}` to exactly one `.cpp` file. This is the best option if you don’t want a header-only library.
- Make a `getColor` `static const sf::Color& getSnakeColor()` *method* which has a `static` constant inside it, and return that. The `static` keyword has a slightly different meaning inside a function, and you can then do what you want there. However, this means you need to change the syntax of how you use it.
- Use a namespace, as you suggested in your answer. If everything else is in `namespace snake`, then you put these variables in `snake::details`, then by convention people will know they shouldn’t look there. Unlike the other options, this isn’t enforced, though.
- File a feature request with SFML to get `Vector2u` and `Color` made into literal types so you can use `constexpr`. Obviously this takes longer and isn’t guaranteed to work.
- Re-order the class to put the members in a more useful order, [as suggested by VTT in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152302/force-in-class-const-member-of-class-to-be-evaluated-at-compile-time#comment77273800_45152302). This is the same as the first option, which I said I liked the most, but keeping them as constants with the same value for every instance of the class. The reason I put it at the bottom of the list is that this will mean that *every copy* of your class will carry around a copy of the color and the window size around, when you only actually need one.

There are probably other options I forgot. For example, there’s a way involving a helper template class which you can use to get a header-only library, without `inline` member variable support and without having to switch to a function call to access the data, and where the `private` specifier is enforced. I can’t quite remember how to make it work, though, and it’s more complex than it’s usually worth.

Comment: Does Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 have support of C++17 features, or do I have to enable it?

Comment: I am fairly sure you can enable support for some C++17 features, but I don’t know if that’s one of them and I don’t know how.

Comment: You know what, I decided to change my mind and instead use the first bullet point. You are right, this should be the best option.